# Using rails_admin to display dropdown list on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` to manage data in a rails application.

I have this class:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :category_id
  belongs_to :category, :inverse_of => :activities
end
```

And the other end is:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :category_id, :activities_ids
  has_many :activities, :inverse_of => :category
end
```

My rails_admin initialiser for Activity looks like this:

```
config.model Activity do
  edit do
    field :title
    field :content, :text do
      bootstrap_wysihtml5 true
    end
    field :category
  end
end
```

Now, in the form it renders the category like this:

[image: Missing field]

It is supposed to render the names of categories, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like it should work, are there definitely categories currently defined, i.e. not blank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking for this for quite a while. To get a really nice autocomplete dropdown just add:

```
config.model Activity do
  edit do
    field :category, :belongs_to_association
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this with a similar belongs_to association and the associated records still show as Station #1 Station #2.  Any thoughts on why?  I want the actual station names to display instead of the objects.